# Windows 10 - Blank screen after sleep mode

Tags: sleep, mode

I've been encountering this issue very often since I got my new PC last December: when I wake the computer from sleep mode, about 1 time out of 3, I get a blank screen, no login window or anything. The screen doesn't look glitchy of fuzzy - it's just a plain grey screen. Sometimes, the cursor appears, but I can't click on anything. Sometimes there's no cursor at all.
I have to force-restart the computer using the power button on the case to get the monitor back, which is probably not the best solution...

I haven't been able to establish a clear pattern for when this occurs - it seems quite random, but it happens often (about 1 time out of 3 as I said above).

The computer is running on Windows 10, updated to the latest version. (Automatic updates).
I was wondering if the issue was caused by the Nvidia drivers or my graphics card (GTX 1080Ti). I've tried updating the driver, it didn't work, so I've also tried switching back to an older version, without success.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you go into device manager and click your graphics card, properties, then roll back driver? or did you find an old version of the driver to install manually? Have you opened up your pc to reseat the graphics card?

Comment: @KyleH Thanks for your reply! Yes, I did try to roll back the driver, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :/